# Document Delphi DLL Exports

Tags: delphi, dll, documentation, delphi-xe4

I have a DLL with many export functions that I would like to share to other people. 
Is there a way to document all existing export functions with parameters, results, etc. so I can share them with others without writing them down by myself?

Comment: You can write documentation. This would complement the import units you supply with the DLL.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? Because later versions such as XE2 have a documentation capability.

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm using Delphi XE-4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a later version of Delphi such as XE2, you might have [Documentation Insight](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42394) which I just confirmed works for exported functions. In your code, click on the function/procedure definition. Let's say for example...

```
procedure DoIt(One: Single; Two: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  //some other code
end;
```

Once you have clicked on this and the cursor is within this function, press the combination `CTRL + ALT + D`. If you have this documentation feature, it will open a small window such as...

[image: Code Documentation Window]

After typing some documentation into this window, it will automatically insert this into your code:

```
/// <summary>
///   This procedure does this and then that
/// </summary>
/// <param name="One">
///   This is parameter one
/// </param>
/// <param name="Two">
///   This is parameter two
/// </param>
/// <remarks>
///   Use DoIt to do this and that within your Delphi project.
/// </remarks>
procedure DoIt(One: Single; Two: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  //some other code
end;
```

[Refer here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/XML_Documentation_for_Delphi_Code) for more information on how to further use this documentation, and also [this one](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/XML_Documentation_Comments) as well.

What's neat about using this is anywhere in your source that you hover your mouse over one of your documented classes, functions, types, etc., it will show a small hint window with your documented information. As for using in DLL's, I've never done it, but I'm sure you can use it there too.

You're also more than free to type this format of documentation directly in your code without using this window - so basically you can do it on any version of Delphi. It's a Microsoft standard format which is used in other languages too.

Unfortunately I'm not sure exactly which versions / editions of Delphi support it.

Comment: You should really inspect that window more closely. This is 3rd party "value adding" add-in.

Comment: @OnTheFly Yes, I realize it's most likely a third-party add-in, this is why I said "you might have..." but it does what the OP wants, so what's the issue? It came with my installation of RAD Studio XE2 automatically, I accidentally discovered it.

Comment: @OnTheFly Even if it were a separate add-in which I had to download and install myself, this is still completely relevant to the question.

Comment: Issue is what virtually all still used Delphi versions are supported, since it is not a built-in feature. Not for free, tho.

Comment: Please inspect it, you are missing a lot of relevant information on add-in.

Comment: @OnTheFly See my edit. You don't even need any add-in installed to be able to document your code the same way. It's a standard Microsoft format.

Comment: I have no disagreement about XMLDoc comments description, but IMHO you have to provide more info about DevJet's XMLDoc editor. Writing it manually is kinda hardcore for newcomer.

Comment: No tool actually writes documentation

Comment: [As of Delphi XE2](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42394), the 3rd party [Documentation Insight Express](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/feature-matrix/) ships with Delphi/RAD Studio. But the Delphi compiler has been able to emit XML Documentation from the XML Doc comments a lot longer. I can't find online documentation about it but I think it was added around Delphi 2006 or 2007. Need to dig out some old Delphi VMs to verify that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, but at least this lets you break it up into a structured standard format which can then be produced into various fancy documentation templates

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I think it was introduced when Embarcadero took it over

Comment: But I think that Benjamin wants a tool that will write the documentation. That's my point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's what I thought at first too, and still it's easy to mis-interpret the short vague question. I actually down-voted, and had to edit the question a bit later so I could undo my downvote.

Comment: Tools can actually write *better-than-nothing* level documentation by themselves (extracting arguments, its data types and the type of return value to the corresponding XMLDoc tags). However, I've never seen `exports` analysis in them.

Comment: @OnTheFly It does make total sense, any DLL's exported functions should theoretically be documented for its usage

Comment: @OnTheFly I disagree. The function declaration provides all of that too. And in a more concise form. What's always missing is the semantics. That always has to be written by a human.

Comment: I don't have the full version of it but it helps a little. Thank you very much!